# Mixing DAO and service calls

Tags: java, architecture

Let's say we have some layer above service layer, with web controllers for example. Service layer is in turn above DAO/Repo layer. In the upper layer the service calls are used alongside repo calls. It breaks the layering of the application to some extent, but should we really bother about wrapping repo methods like `findAll()` into service methods. I don't think so. Are there any drawbacks that might cause a lot of pain because of such design? Transactional issues?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would turn your question around and say - why not have a service layer for such a method? Is it such a pain to wrap a DAO method like:

```
 public class PersonService {
 ...
     private PersonDao personDao;
 ...
     public List<Person> findAll() {
         return personDao.findAll();
     }
 ...
 }
```

**Client data**
What if you don't want to send back the data entity that represents a Person to your controller? You could map the data in the service layer to an Object that only clients are dependent on.

**Coupling**
You are also coupling your layers. The controller layer should only depend on the service layer and the service layer should only depend on the DAO layer.

**Transactions**
All transactions should be handled at the service layer (as a service method may call multiple DAO methods).

**Business Logic**
All business logic should be in your service layer. Therefore, you should never bypass such logic by calling a DAO directly.

I know, for a method like findAll, it seems pointless but I think the point about layer coupling defeats that argument.

Comment: +1. One additional point might be security. If you use method-level security and wrap the DAO calls in service, you only have one place to secure (the service) because typically the DAOs can be only called from within some transaction (i.e. from service layer). This assumes that the DAOs themselves are not transactional (which is also a good practice as you mention).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be a pain if some developer used to call DAO layer code directly from other layers i.e. other than Service layer or whatever architecture you are following for this as a solution:
Use maven dependencies create 4-5 different modules for your project and mention the dependencies in `pom.xml` so that no calls will be made from any other incorrect layer.
For making it more clear:-
If you want to access layer 3 only from layer 4 just add one dependency entry in layer 3 for 4 and as no other modules have access to layer 3 they can't call code from it.

You definitely get hundred of example for doing this.